# Mocking the datetime library in pypy raises TypeError when comparing 2 mocked objects

Tags: python, class, datetime, mocking, pypy

I'm doing some tests for my python library which is supposed to work on all python versions - 27, 33, 34, 35, 36 and **pypy**. In my tests I'm mocking the `datetime` library and they all work, except when I run them in `pypy` (see why I bolded that earlier? such a plot twist!).

Here's a MCVE for the trouble I'm having:

```
import mock
import datetime as dtl
mk = mock.Mock(wraps=dtl.datetime)
p = mock.patch('datetime.datetime', mk)
p.start()
from datetime import datetime
d1 = datetime.now()
d2 = datetime.now()
print d1 == d2
```

In all python versions the last line returns `False`. In `pypy` the last line throws:

```
>>>> d1 == d2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pypy/lib_pypy/datetime.py", line 1764, in __eq__
    if isinstance(other, datetime):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

I dug through `pypy`'s source code trying to understand the problem, and why on earth are there differences between it and other python versions, and I found the following:

```
# Comparisons of datetime objects with other.

def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, datetime):
        return self._cmp(other) == 0
    elif hasattr(other, "timetuple") and not isinstance(other, date):
        return NotImplemented
    else:
        return False
```

This kind of makes sense. The `datetime` class is now a `Mock` object - and python insists that the second argument to `isinstance` will be a type. Neato.

So I decided to look at cpython's implementation of `datetime`, and surprise surprise:

```
# Comparisons of datetime objects with other.

def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, datetime):
        return self._cmp(other, allow_mixed=True) == 0
    elif not isinstance(other, date):
        return NotImplemented
    else:
        return False
```

The same exact verification is done here, yet it does not raise anything `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

I'll add that this happens in python 2.7:

```
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 7, 9, 31, 50, 838155)
>>> d == d
True
>>> datetime
<Mock id='139788521555024'>
>>> isinstance(d, datetime)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

There are 2 questions I'm struggling with:

1. Why on earth does it work for cpython?
2. How can I mock the datetime object in a way that this will work without reimplementing `__eq__` or any other magic method :)

Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

That's a real problem in python and a good example why using `isinstanceof` is a bad practice.

The solution is to not patch with a mock, but rather with a class inheriting from `datetime.datetime`. But, because you will inherit from datetime and still want to check the type based on the real `datetime` class we will need to override the `isinstance` check to be on the real class.

```
import datetime as dtl
import mock

real_datetime_class = dtl.datetime

class DatetimeSubclassMeta(type):
    """Datetime mock metaclass to check instancechek to the real class."""

    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(mcs, obj):
        return isinstance(obj, real_datetime_class)

class BaseMockedDatetime(real_datetime_class):
    """Mock class to cover datetime class."""

MockedDatetime = DatetimeSubclassMeta('datetime',
                                      (BaseMockedDatetime,),
                                      {})

p = mock.patch('datetime.datetime', MockedDatetime)
p.start()


from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()

isinstance(d, datetime)
```

- Solution is based on: http://blog.xelnor.net/python-mocking-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

As for "why", it probably has to do with `datetime` being implemented in C in CPython, and pure python in PyPy, and some subtle differences between a Python class object and a builtin C one.